# Perforce: Get list of changelists before and after a changelist

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

Lets say i have a change list `1234`
I want to see the details of changelists before and after `1234`

Is there a command to do that?

I am new to P4 and find it not that great compared to git, basically i want to see an equivalent command in p4 for `git log` and see few commits before and after the commit that is of interest to me (which is equivalent to change list `1234`)

Comment: This is not a git question. Removing the tag.

Comment: okay, i thought people who are familiar with git could relate to my question, but agree it is not a git question..

Comment: I understand the line of thought but it's not appropriate to use the tag because the question is not about git. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `p4 changes` command with a revision range.  Revision ranges can be changelist numbers, revision numbers, dates, or labels.

```
C:\Perforce\workshop>p4 changes @1230,1238
Change 1238 on 2002/01/08 by richard_geiger@rmg:intjam:chinacat 'Pass a void *closure parameter '
Change 1237 on 2002/01/08 by richard_geiger@rmg:intjam:chinacat 'Experimental support for runnin'
Change 1236 on 2002/01/08 by richard_geiger@rmg:intjam:chinacat 'Prepare template for next relea'
Change 1235 on 2002/01/08 by david_abrahams@morepie 'Files not in the original Jam d'
Change 1234 on 2002/01/08 by david_abrahams@morepie 'Newly added files were missing '
Change 1233 on 2002/01/07 by jonathan_kamens@jonathan_kamens 'Update the coument documenting '
Change 1232 on 2002/01/07 by craig_mcpheeters@craig_mcpheeters-home 'Clarified the error on invalid '
Change 1231 on 2002/01/06 by craig_mcpheeters@craig_mcpheeters-home 'Oops, forgot about NT.  Changed'
Change 1230 on 2002/01/06 by craig_mcpheeters@craig_mcpheeters-home 'This contains alterations to Ma'
```